# Change a div class when a radio option inside it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first real dive into javascript. I've been going at this for hours and haven't found a solution (though I learned a lot).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeClass(){
    var NAME = document.getElementById("switcher");
    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if (currentClass == "switch switch-blue") { 
        NAME.className = "switch switch-red";   
    } else {
        NAME.className = "switch switch-blue";  
    }
} 
 window.onload = function()
    {
        document.getElementById("switcher").addEventListener( 'click' , changeClass );
    }

</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="switch switch-blue" id="switcher">
 <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="resp" value="1" id="respyes" checked>
 <label for="respyes" class="switch-label">YES</label>
 <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="resp" value="2" id="respno">
 <label for="respno" class="switch-label">NO</label>
</div>
```

The default is a blue background. If they choose no I want it red, then back to blue if they click yes, all that is in the css. If I manually change the class from switch-blue to switch-red, it works. Right now it does absolutely nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: is your desire to use jQuery for this (hence the tagging?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is event propagation when an internal element click event bubbleup so it causing calling your function twice which change class and then revert back so try:

```
function changeClass(event) {
    var NAME = document.getElementById("switcher");

    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if (currentClass == "switch switch-blue") {
        NAME.className = "switch switch-red";
    } else {
        NAME.className = "switch switch-blue";
    }
    if (window.event != undefined) window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    event.stopPropagation();
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("switcher").addEventListener('click', changeClass);
}
```

`event.stopPropagation();` will stop this bubbling and for IE use `window.event.cancelBubble = true;`

[Here is working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Euv5F/5/)

### Edit

But this will not guarentee the change of class on radio button click as event is bind to parent div so clicking over div anywhere will trigger the event, so try to bind event on the radio-buttons:

[Event on Radio click](http://jsfiddle.net/Euv5F/8/)

```
function changeClass(clickedItem) {
    var NAME = document.getElementById("switcher");

    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if (clickedItem == 1) {
        NAME.className = "switch switch-red";
    } else {
        NAME.className = "switch switch-blue";
    }
}
window.onload = function () {

    var yes = document.getElementById('respyes');
    var no = document.getElementById('respno');
    yes.onclick = function () {
        changeClass(2)
    };
    no.onclick = function () {
        changeClass(1)
    };
}
```

Comment: The background changes whenever you click the div. Try clicking outside the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working fine, when you add the css classes.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Euv5F/1/). I think you are missing the styles.
Add the style to your head and see if that works for you.

```
<style>
.switch-blue{
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
}
.switch-red{
    background:red;
      color:#fff;
}</style>
```

Feel free to change the styles as you need them.

**Edit**
I just noticed that you have the event listeners attached to the div instead of the radio button. That will change the background when you click the div, instead of the buttons. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Euv5F/6/).

Comment: The click event will propogate up to the div.

Comment: I was a little worried it might not propagate, as well, but my testing in Chrome so far shows the event bubbling, too. Could be an issue with some versions of IE, however, if memory serves.

Comment: Yup, I agree. It does.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeClass(elem){
    var currentClass = elem.className, blueClass = "switch switch-blue", 
        redClass= "switch switch-red"
    elem.className = (currentClass == blueClass) ? redClass:blueClass;
} 

window.onload = function()
{
        document.getElementById("switcher").onclick = function(){
           changeClass(this);
        };
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dYt8v/